# Help with a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am dealing with a differential Eq. with the form $y''+ p(t)y'+q(t)y = 0$, introducing the function $Y=sin(t^2)$, but in an awkward step forward I found that:

$sin(t^2)(q(t)-4t^2)+cos(t^2)(2tp(t)+2)=0$

turns into:

$(2tp(t)+2)=0$

I've been wondering how is this possible, I've used a lot of algebra and even the obvious solution $pc_1+qc_2=0$ but I still can't explain it myself, please help, thanks a lot.  *This excersice can be found in Boyce Di Prima Book*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've finally found the right answer, I omitted the fact that p(t) and q(t) are continuous coefficients, thus they are finite, but if I fit t=0 in the t values $sin (t^2)$ eliminates its partners